# Encapsulate strings in an array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Due to layer 8 issues, I am required to set mailbox delegation permissions in [Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server). I have written my first functional PowerShell script to do this for me and all is well, aside from the dreaded

-GrantSendOnBehalfTo

I was confused for a while until I realized that only the last name in my array was getting the permission, and so I found that when you run the command it wipes out any existing entries.

Let's say Bob has send on behalf for Joe's mailbox and Ben also needs it. I run

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity Joe -GrantSendOnBehalfTo Ben
```

Ben will get it and Bob will lose it.

So I dug and found that you can supply multiple users in one command and this works, formats like this:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity Joe -GrantSendOnBehalfTo  @{Add="Bob", "Ben"}
```

So I want to pass my array built from some lists:

```
function test-Array($mailbox) {
    $target= Get-Content .\list\$list.txt
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$target}
}
```

This will obviously fail because the output of $target is:

```
Bob Ben
```

So my question is: How can I append the strings so that they are the following?

```
"Bob", "Ben",
```

I have tried

```
$separator = "", ""
[string]::Join($separator,$target)
```

But due to PowerShell being evil, it does not see `"` as part of my separator.

Sorry to seem the fool. I have looked around and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Resolution:

```
$separator = '", "'
$tgt= [string]::Join($separator,$target)
$tgt = $tgt + '"'
$tgt = $tgt.Insert(0,'"')
```

OR

```
$separator = '", "'
$target= $target -replace '^|$','"' -join ','
```

Comment: A lot if not all of the Exchange context provided makes no difference; this is a simple string manipulation question (in powershell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately just setting the separator will only set the quotes between elements.  It's going to miss the first and last quote.

```
$target = 'Bob','Ben'

$target -replace '^|$','"' -join ','

"Bob","Ben"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function test-Array($mailbox){
     $target= Get-Content .\list\$list.txt
     Foreach($User in $Target){
          Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$User}
     }
}
```

Comment: the trouble with doing in that way is that it overwrites the permissions from the last application of the Set-Mailbox command, so effectively only the last entry in the array gets the permission

Comment: What version of Exchange and Powershell are you running? I just tried using Powershell v4 and Exchange 2013 and as I expected it works flawlessly.

Comment: Exchange 2010 and im unsure of the powershell version il check it in the morning and update here